# How can I read session variable value in Laravel AppServiceProvider to get login data?

Tags: laravel

I'm always getting NULL value after I `dd($user)` my variable using Laravel 5.7.

Here is my code:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    $notifications = Messages::where('is_read', 0)->limit(5)->get();
    $user = User::where('id', session('user'))->first();
    dd($user);
    View::share('logged_user', $user);
    View::share('notifications', $notifications);
}
```

Comment: Try to debug by show your `session('user')` . ex: `dd(session('user'))`

Comment: returned NULL , but in my Controller session can be read

Comment: can you post full code of appServiceProvider.php ?. maybe you have to add 'use Session;'

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Messages;
use App\User;
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        $notifications = Messages::where('is_read', 0)->limit(3)->get();
        View::share('notifications', $notifications);  
    }

  
}

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't read session directly from a service provider :

In Laravel the session is handled by `StartSession` Middleware that executes after all the service providers `boot` phase.

If you want to share a session variable with all view, you can use a view [composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) from your service provider:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
        {
            // dd(\Session::get('var')) not work. Its work on view.
            $view->with('your_var', \Session::get('var') );    
        });  
    }
```

Comment: can you provide example on how to retrieve session variable or how to share session variable to all views? i've just tried the code above but i didn't get the exact answer